# ECS Fargate Extra Hosts

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am in middle of switching from EC2 to ECS Fargate to host my laravel api and I am using laravel passport oauth function with guzzle to generate access tokens. However in order for this to work I have to add an entry to extra_hosts like example.com:10.20.10.140 to my docker-compose.yml.

It looks like I cannot add an extra host entry via Fargate would really appreciate if anyone know of an alternative solution to this problem as the application works perfectly fine on local as well as on ec2.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The way I worked around similar limitations in the past (e.g. for me it was `searchdomain`) is to add a line in a startup script that hack the local file. This is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash

# when the variable is populated a search domain entry is added to resolv.conf at startup
# this is needed for the ECS service discovery given the app works by calling host names and not FQDNs
# a search domain can't be added to the container when using the awsvpc mode 
# and the awsvpc mode is needed for A records (bridge only supports SRV records)
if [ $SEARCH_DOMAIN ]; then echo "search ${SEARCH_DOMAIN}" >> /etc/resolv.conf; fi 

ruby /app/yelb-appserver.rb -o 0.0.0.0
```

[Link to source](https://github.com/mreferre/yelb/blob/master/yelb-appserver/startup.sh)

If you do not want to change the main container/application to do this you can have a sidecar container in the same task that only does this and then exits.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I just gave that a go and it is giving me error /bin/sh: can't create /etc/resolv.conf: Permission denied.

Comment: mh.... is it possible that you are running your container with a non root user (which would be a good thing to do)? If so, can you sudo echo? I believe my container runs as root (shame on me) so I haven't seen it.